# Finding the index of an element within a live function

Tags: jquery

I'm creating new < li > elements with a live() click function, but jquery won't tell me the index of newly created elements. Here's the code:

```
    $esl = $('.dynamicLink');
    $esl.live('click',function(){
        var dynamicIndex = $esl.index(this);
        alert(dynamicIndex);
    });
```

Whenever I click the dynamicLink, it returns "-1" as the index. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `live` uses event delegation to "bind" events to future elements, you need to call `index` on an up-to-date list of elements. Try this:

```
$esl = $('.dynamicLink');
$esl.live('click',function(){
    var dynamicIndex = $('.dynamicLink').index(this);
    alert(dynamicIndex);
});
```